# На cms wordpress обнаружен скрытый <iframe>

Tags: html, wordpress, вирусы

Добрый день, на моем блоге, с помощью виджета Firebug был обнаружен скрытый , который ссылается на неизвестный сайт.

```
<iframe src="https://static.hupso.com/share/js/service.html?r_x=&w_x=share_toolbar.js&n_x=" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: 0px;"/>
```

Домен и хостинг был приобретен 6 дней назад, и я не знаю где я мог подхватить данную проблему. Плагины использую проверенные.
Писал в тех поддержку, они тоже мне указали на этот скрытый файл. А как его вычислить и удалить, я не знаю. Подскажите?

Comment: В индексном файле вп шаблона, удали весь код, и смотри если этот код остался - значит дело не в шаблоне, а в ядре или плагинах. Так по одному отключать, и тестить откуда он вылезает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, это вот этот плагин:

https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/hupso-share-buttons-for-twitter-facebook-google/

Просто собирает статистику по нажатым социалкам

Comment: Вы правы, действительно скрытый элемент исчез. Спасибо

Comment: @Sergiyss Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Crantisz попрошайка)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не согласен, даже в виде шутки. Отмеченные галкой ответы нужны. Я сам ищу ответы на SO, читая в основном только отмеченные галкой.

Comment: @KAGGDesign оффтопя, но... галка - не значит, что решение верное (высказывание не касается ответа выше). Она значит, что решение помогло автору вопроса. А вот верное вполне может быть без галки в каком-нибудь соседнем ответе. Это, кстати, не редкость на enSO и бывает с галкой +10 ответ, а вот с хорошим решением, качественным объяснением проблемы и решением с +200 может висеть без оной... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский согласен, но лучше все же правильные ответы отмечать галкой и явно просить об этом новых участников

Comment: @АлексейШиманский : https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1223/223191

Comment: @Crantisz замечу что "Цель: попросить автора вопроса отметить тот ответ «верным», который помог ему в решении задачи. ..... Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)." **!==** "Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение."

Answer (score 0):

> Плагины использую проверенные

Кем "проверенные"? Плагины и темы нужно использовать только из [оф каталога](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/) и не древние.

> А как его вычислить и удалить, я не знаю. Подскажите?

Может лучше сразу "избавиться", а не заниматься "вычислениями"?
Тогда заменить ядро ВП через  удаление. Избавиться от дырявых тем и плагинов. Провести ревизию файлов и БД. Поставить надёжные пароли везде.